# How can i remove the in a grid

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, grid

I want to remove the count in the gird. Here it is showing 5 records found, i want to remove this. I am using grid.php to create the gird and not ui components.

[image]

Class grid.php in block folder

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    try{

        $collection =$this->_collectionFactory->create()
            ->addFieldToSelect('product_id')
            ->distinct(true);


        $this->setCollection($collection);

        parent::_prepareCollection();

        return $this;
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();die;
    }
}

protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    $this->addColumn(
        'product_id',
        [
            'header' => __('Product'),
            'index' => 'product_id',
            'class' => 'product_id'
        ]
    );



    $block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('grid.bottom.links');
    if ($block) {
        $this->setChild('grid.bottom.links', $block);
    }

    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}
```

Comment: which grid is it and what have you tried?

Comment: It's a custom grid created by me using grid.php

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: Now check if you get any idea

Comment: you either have to overwrite the default template or remove the whole pagination component

Comment: take a look at this file: vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/widget/grid/extended.phtml

Comment: How can i override this template